# Variable Scope in Javascript GeoLocation not Working

Tags: javascript, scope

This is very simple issue, but unable to solve, i.e Variable scope in javascript for geoLocation values not working. Here is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">


        var glat;
        var glng;
        var test = "Hiii";
    function call(){
                var lat;
                var lng;
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var address = "Delhi";
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                    lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                    } 

            glat = lat;
            glng = lng;
            alert("In: "+glat + glng+ "Test: "+test);
            //All Values Displayed Fine..
            }); 
        alert("OUT: "+glat + glng+ "Test: "+test);
        //glat and glng displayed as undefined..

    }
</script>
```

Why, the values in OUT alert not displaying..?? How can I solve this..

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: This *must* be a dupe of some other question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the geo info is an async process, you should do such job with a callback.

***Example:***

```
function call(address, callback) {
    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        var lat, lng;
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        }
        callback(lat, lng);
    });
}

//usage:
call("Delhi", function (glat, glng) {
    // if you still get undefined, it means the status is not OK.
    alert("OUT: " + glat + glng);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `geocoder.geocode([object],[callback]);` takes a function as second parameter, which is called *asynchronously*: The `glat` and `glng` variables therefore aren't set until the request is completed, and the callback function as returned. The basic flow of your snippet is this:

```
declare variables
declare function [call]
    local variables for function
    make async request
    alert "out" + glat + glen //Just after request is sent, not after it's completed
    [call] returns
//time passes
       on successful completion of request://<--refs back to request set in [call]
           set variables glat and glng
           alert "In"
```